# Exchange of norm and limit in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I'm quite confused about this topic. Since a norm is a continuous function (using the topology inducted by the norm), it should hold by definition that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}||x_n||=||\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n||=||x||$$

So it is possible to exchange norm and limit.

But it seems that it is not always true: for example, when we want to show that $(C[0,1],||\cdot||_{\infty})$ is a Banach space we don't use directly this argument, but we pass to the absolute value in order to exchange the limit. To be precise, after having found a candidate $f$ as limit of $f_n$ (Cauchy sequence), we do:
$||f_n-f_m||<\epsilon$ for proper $n,m$, then $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon \forall x$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=|\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)-f_m(x)|=|f(x)-f_m(x)|\leq\epsilon \forall x$, and so we can con conclude that also $||f-f_m||\leq\epsilon$. But why we don't perform directly: $||f-f_m||=||\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n-f_m||=\lim_{n\to\infty}||f_n-f_m||<\epsilon$?

Where I am wrong?

Comment: To be able to apply the argument with continuity, you must have $\lim x_n = x$ which by continuity implies $\lim ||x_n|| = ||x||$. But the problematic part usually is showing that the limit exists and is the specific $x$.

Comment: Saying $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence does **not** imply that $\lim_n(f_n-f_m)=0$. (Obviously not, otherwise for example $\lim_n f_n=f_m$ for _every_ $m$...)

Comment: Consider the Banach space $\mathbb{R}$ with its Euclidean norm, and let $x_n = (-1)^n$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\| = 1$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple. You first need to establish that $\lim_n x_n$ exists, before you can start doing these manipulations.

Of course, in the Banach space proof, showing that this limit exists is the end goal.

Comment: Oh ok, it was simple, thank you

Comment: @francescoa Hi. If this answer helped you, you may consider accepting it to let other people know your question is solved :)

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @francescoa Near the amount of votes should be a button you can click. Once you clicked it, it should become green.

Answer (score 2):

Because we don't know that $||f_n -f ||_{\infty } \to 0.$ We only know that $f_n(x) \to f(x) $ uniformly for all $x\in X.$ So we have to use the fact to prove that $||f_n -f ||_{\infty } \to 0.$